# second time key in password cant enter

Tags: c

This is login system, when i first time key in wrong password can enter but second time key in the password cant accept the enter key. it cant accept any key i put. first time key in can put enter and compare is valid will jump out the loop. now only the second time key in cant put enter to login sucessfull.

```
struct registers
{
    char id[26];
    char password[26];
}user,userLogin;

int login() {
    int i = 0, c = 0;
    char ch;
    FILE*pwd;
    struct userLogin;
    struct user;
    pwd = fopen("password.bin", "rb");
    fread(&user, sizeof(struct registers), 1, pwd);
    do {
        i = 0;//if worng key in first time the userLogin.password[i] will set with zero
        printf("Enter user ID:");
        scanf("%s", &userLogin.id);
        printf("enter user password:");
        while (1) {//this is print out the star when user key in password
            ch = getch();
            if (ch == ENTER || ch == TAB) {
                userLogin.password[i++] = '\0'; 
                break;
            }
            else if (ch == BS) {//when user key in wrong password can delete the password
                if (i > 0) {
                    userLogin.password[i--] = '\0';
                    //i--;
                    printf("\b \b");
                }
            }
            else {
                userLogin.password[i++] = ch;
                printf("* \b");
            }
        }
        while (1) {//compare the user key in password and id and check the file
            if (strcmp(user.id, userLogin.id) == 0 && strcmp(user.password, userLogin.password) == 0) {
                system("cls");
                printf("Login Sucessful!!!\n");
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                if (!feof(pwd)){//it will read all data stock in the file
                    fread(&user, sizeof(struct registers), 1, pwd);
                }
                else { 
                    system("cls");
                    printf("Invalid password or user id Pls Try Again\n");
                    fclose(pwd);
                    c++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (strcmp(user.id, userLogin.id) == 0 && strcmp(user.password, userLogin.password) == 0) {
            break;//this will check again if login it same will jump out loop
    } while (c != 5);
    if (c == 5) //if wrong 5 time will close the system
        exit(-1);
    fclose(pwd);
```

Comment: can you show the whole source code

Comment: okei edit alr..

Comment: the posted code is not even a complete function! please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and then help you debug it.

Comment: what is the definition of: `struct user`? What is the definition of `struct userlogin`?  What is definition of `struct registers`?

Comment: regarding: `if (!feof(pwd)){//it will read all data stock in the file
                    fread(&user, sizeof(struct registers), 1, pwd);`  Much better to eliminate the call to `feof()` and use the returned value (not the parameter values) from the call to `fread()`

Comment: regarding: `pwd = fopen("password.bin", "rb");
    fread(&user, sizeof(struct registers), 1, pwd);`  always check the returned value from calls to c library functions to assure those functions were successful.

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%25s", &userLogin.id);`  1) always check the returned value from a call to any of the `scanf()` family of functions to assure the operation was successful.  2) since `userLogin.id` is an array of 26 characters, the `&` is not correct as a bare reference to an array name degrades to the address of the first byte of the array.

Comment: regarding: `else
            continue;`  these two statements are completely unnecessary because the next statement (which is a `while()`) at the bottom of the loop will cause a branch back to the top of the loop

Comment: please post the contents of the `password.bin` file.  And such a file is encrypted, however, I do not see any code to encrypt the user entered password, before comparing it to the encrypted password in the file

Comment: regarding: `ch = getch();`  The function: `getch()` is NOT portable.  Suggest using: `getchar()`

Comment: regarding: `if (ch == ENTER || ch == TAB) {`  What is the definition of `ENTER`? What is the definition of `TAB`?  What is the definition of `BS`?

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%25s", &userLogin.id);`  this will leave the '\n' in `stdin` so the first thing the code will see when trying to input the password will be the `\n` which will be caught by: `if (ch == ENTER || ch == TAB) {
                userLogin.password[i++] = '\0'; 
                break;` resulting in the password never being read until the next iteration through the loop.

Comment: `ENTER` is enter key i use for ascii ,`BS` is backspace,`TAB` is tab

Comment: `ch=getch()` i use this to print * when user key in password

Comment: but now is when i first time wrong password after i key in second time password it cant accept enter